# How to extracting method's parameter names, and use them as a Dictionary keys?

Tags: c#, reflection, refactoring, c#-5.0, code-duplication

Imagine there is a simple method like this:

```
public async Task<ValidatePhoneNumberResult> ValidatePhoneNumberAsync(
    string phone_number,
    string country_code,
    string country_iso,
    DeviceUuid device_uuid, // DeviceUuid supports his own ToString();
    string os_name,
    string os_version,
    string model,
    string screen_resolution,
    string sim_operator = "00000",
    string is_usim = null
    )
{
    Uri uri = new Uri(MY_URI);
    HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, uri);

    Dictionary<string, string> dic = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    dic.Add("phone_number", phone_number.ToString());
    dic.Add("country_code", country_code.ToString());
    dic.Add("country_iso", country_iso.ToString());
    dic.Add("os_name", os_name.ToString());
    dic.Add("model", model.ToString());
    dic.Add("screen_resolution", screen_resolution.ToString());
    dic.Add("sim_operator", sim_operator.ToString());
    if (is_usim != null)
    {
        dic.Add("is_usim", is_usim.ToString());
    }

    request.Content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(dic);
    return await GetResult<ValidatePhoneNumberResult>(request);
}
```

This is my first design. I will make a lot of functions like that from now.
But the code has something I don't like. It is the part of adding parameters to a dictionary. I think it is obvious code duplication.

- All parameter names are used as the dictionary's keys.
- And they all will implement their own ToString() method.
- If parameter is `null`, it shouldn't be put in dictionary.

It would be better, if it could:

```
Dictionary<string, string> dic = new Dictionary<string, string>();
dic.Add("phone_number", phone_number.ToString());
dic.Add("country_code", country_code.ToString());
dic.Add("country_iso", country_iso.ToString());
dic.Add("os_name", os_name.ToString());
dic.Add("model", model.ToString());
dic.Add("screen_resolution", screen_resolution.ToString());
dic.Add("sim_operator", sim_operator.ToString());
if (is_usim != null)
{
    dic.Add("is_usim", is_usim.ToString());
}

// To
var dic = ExtractParametersAndMakeItAsDictionary();
```

How to make this code using C#(5.0) syntax? If you have a better suggestion, I will be happy to hear.
If it is impossible, is that possible wrapping it with `macro`?(as we often did when we write `C`) 
Tell me any possible idea to deduplicate the code :)

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't look like it's possible to do easily: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1867482/c-sharp-getting-value-of-parms-using-reflection

Comment: @Matthew Thanks. The question has been modified slightly.

Comment: There are no macros in C#.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this approach:

```
public void SomeMethod(string p1, int p2, object p3)
{
    Dictionary<string, string> dic = ExtractParametersAndMakeItAsDictionary(p1, p2, p3);
}

private Dictionary<string, string> ExtractParametersAndMakeItAsDictionary(params object[] parameters)
{
    StackTrace stackTrace = new StackTrace();
    string methodName = stackTrace.GetFrame(1).GetMethod().Name;
    ParameterInfo[] parameterInfos = GetType().GetMethod(methodName).GetParameters();

    return parameters.Where(p => p != null).Zip(parameterInfos, (pv, pi) => new { Name = pi.Name, Value = pv.ToString() }).ToDictionary(x => x.Name, x => x.Value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use a [DTO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_Transfer_Object) instead? It would make serialization a lot easier.

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static Dictionary<string, string> ToDicionary(this object o)
    {
        var dic = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        foreach(var property in o.GetType().GetProperties())
        {
            dic.Add(property.Name, string.Format("{0}", property.GetValue(o)));
        }

        return dic;
    }
}
```

You don't even need to change the way you call it much if you use object initialization syntax:

```
public async Task<ValidatePhoneNumberResult> ValidatePhoneNumberAsync(object dto)
{
    Uri uri = new Uri(MY_URI);
    HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, uri);

    request.Content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(dto.ToDictionary());
    return await GetResult<ValidatePhoneNumberResult>(request);
}
```

You don't even need to create a type for it:

```
var result = await ValidatePhoneNumberAsync(
    new
    {
            phone_number = "000000000",
            country_code = "code",
            country_iso = "iso",
            device_uuid = new DeviceUuid(),
            os_name = "Windows",
            os_version = "6.3",
            model = "model",
            screen_resolution = "4K",
            sim_operator = "00000",
            is_usim = null
    });
```

Comment: The problem with the `object` approach is that it's not type-safe. If you forget to specify one of the parameters, or mistype its name, you're not going to get a compile error.