# Access "autos" in process (at runtime)

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, debugging, reflection

Is it somehow possible to access the debuggers "autos" from code/in-process? E.g. to create a dump of all members/variables and their respective values from the current scope?

[image: autos]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get some information shown there, but not all.

You can get the current classes' properties and fields using reflection. Simply use [`GetProperties`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1197004/993547) for example. You have to make that call from the method you are executing though, no way to get to know which instance is in the call stack now.

[You can't](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1867496/993547) get the parameters and variable values from the current method call.