# How to get Function formal parameters' list dynamically in C#?

Tags: c#, function, reflection

I have a class file in which, I am trying to read another function's formal parameters by passing the name of the function.
But somehow, below code is not working:

```
public string Post([FromBody]string value)
{
    string result = String.Empty;
    JObject json = JObject.Parse(value);
    string funcname = json["functionname"].Value<string>();

        method.Method.GetParameters ( ) [ index ].Name ;

    //typeof(MyType).GetMethod(json).Invoke(null, new [] {arg1, arg2}) //need to parameter list here
    //GetSearch(string text)

    return result;
}
```

Is this possible with Reflection? Or with Realproxy?

Comment: What is the `method` here? Can you share the complete code?

Comment: "It is not working" has never been a sufficient problem description. | Yes, Reflection is the droid you are looking for with your stated Problem. | However I noticed that a lot of people end up with reflection, as result of a XY problem. | Some code - like (de)serializers or struct.Equals() - has to use reflection to work at all. It is a reliable - but slow - fallback. But you are always encouraged to make a non-reflection, proper function instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can use reflection as:

```
var type = typeof(T);
var method = type.GetMethod(methodName);
var parameters = method.GetParameters();
```

where `T` is your class type. You can get the data you need from each `ParameterInfo` object.

Answer (score 0):

After retrieving the `MethodInfo` of the Method named after the value of the variable `funcname`,

```
MethodInfo mInfo = typeof(MyType).GetMethod(funcname);
```

I suggest you store the store the parameter names you are going to use and their corresponding values into an `Dictionary`, for example:

```
Dictionary<string, object> parameterValues = new Dictionary<string, object>()
{
    { "id", 3 },
    { "name", "John" },
    { "size", 1.00 }
};
```

Then just loop through `MethodInfo.GetParameters()` and add the parameter values with matching name into a list of objects.

```
var invokingParemeters = new List<object>();

foreach (var parameter in mInfo.GetParameters())
{
    if (parameterValues.ContainsKey(parameter.Name))
    {
        invokingParemeters.Add(parameterValues[parameter.Name]);
    }
}
```

Finally, pass this list into the `.Invoke()`

```
mInfo.Invoke(null, invokingParemeters.ToArray());
```

Answer (score -1):

For the stated problem, the solution is indeed reflection. However I dislike using reflection. For me it is a fallback, one I should try to avoid. Asking for it is often a indication of a XY problem.

Some code **has** to use Reflection:

- (de)serialisation has to us reflection, to get/put in all the elements
- The code for comparing two structs you made for equality has to use Reflection, or it oculd not work on any random struct you come up with. All existign structs tend to have those functions overridden.
- Entity Framework has to use reflection to generate the classes whose properties it can only know after the query (at runtime).

Reflection is slow. Reflection breaks compile time type checks. For those reasons you are *always encouraged* to provide a explicit, non-reflection function for the job instead.

With this case, it is even a *security risk*. I remember from my PHP days, that either get or put parameter are very dangerous, because an attacker can use them to set *random variables in your code*, if you forgot to initialize them. [SQLInjections are a thing too](https://xkcd.com/327/). And this code allows a attacker to run **almost random functions with whatever arguments they want**.

I have a saver and quicker - because reflection free - option: `Dictionary<string, delegate(string)>`.

- The Key is the name of the function to call.
- the delegate is teh function that is given the JSON, parses it, and then calls the Function.
- If somebody queries for allowed functions? Just give him the KeyCollection
- Need a new entry? That is one line of the Collection initialisation
- Somebody give you a key not in the collection? Invalid argument

If the return type is variable, there are reflection free options for that too. But as long as you wrote every part of the reflection strings, it is not a security risk - just a bit slow.