# Can you get a list of parameters with each parameter's type, value too

Tags: vb.net

example

```
Function Combine(valA as String, valB as String) as String
    Dim strParameters As String = GetParameters(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod())
    Dim strParametersTypesAs String = GetParameters(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod())
    Dim strParametersValuesAs String = GetParameters(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod())

    Debug.WriteLine(strParameters)
    Debug.WriteLine(strParametersTypes)
    Debug.WriteLine(strParametersValues)

    '   OR
    Dim strParamArray() as string = TryCast("valA", Parameter)
    Debug.WriteLine("This is Cast Values: " & strParamArray(0).ToString & strParamArray(1).ToString)

End Function

Combine("Apple", "Shake")
```

output or similar

```
valA, valB
System.String, System.String
"Apple", "Shake"
This is Cast Value: AppleShake
```

Comment: .Net is a static platform, and so the first two are already always known to you. What are you really trying to do here?

Comment: Sounds like an [xy-question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: yes indeed, I have done the first two but scratching my head for the value.

Comment: I have numerous parameters to collect data to save into a database. so what I am trying to do, GetParameters.Name and Value to put everything instantly in the loop and save it into the database as parameter name and DB field names are almost the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can only do the first two, but not the third easily. ParameterInfo (from Reflection) doesn't say anything about values.

See [C# Getting value of params using reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1867482/832052)

But I guess you are combining the values so the output of your function might have what you want to put in the console anyway. This is as close as I can get you:

```vb
Private Function Combine(valA As String, valB As String) As String
    Dim parameterInfos = System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().GetParameters()
    Dim params = parameterInfos.Select(Function(pi) pi.Name)
    Dim paramTypes = parameterInfos.Select(Function(pi) pi.ParameterType)

    Debug.WriteLine(String.Join(", ", params))
    Debug.WriteLine(String.Join(", ", paramTypes))
    Dim result = String.Join(", ", {valA, valB})
    Debug.WriteLine(result)

    Return result
End Function
```

> valA, valB
>
> System.String, System.String
>
> Apple, Shake

Comment: yes indeed, I have done the first two but scratching my head for the value.